# Creating services in sybase central

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-9, sybase-asa

I am creating services in Sybase Central in order to connect my database file to sybase central. It's in this directory "C:\sample\test.db", and I am stuck on the parameters. It asks me: "What parameters do you want to use this service ?" What parameters should I enter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the parameters you want your database to be started with.

From the SQLAnywhere Documentation:

> if you want a network server to run using the sample database with a cache size of 20 MB and the name myserver, you would type the following in the Parameters text box of the Create Service Wizard in Sybase Central:

```
-c 20M
-n myserver "C:\sample\test.db"
```

The `-c 20M` is optional, and `myserver` should be the name of the server.

This link is for the more recent versions of the software, but most of it still applies.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/running-sectb-3454334.html

Comment: Is it okay not to include the -c 20M in my parameter?, aslo is this applicable in my SQLAnywhere version 9 ?

Comment: Version 9 is Adaptive Server Anywhere - not SQL Anywhere..those are the kinds of details to put in your question.  In V9, I believe the options are the same, and `-c` is not required.